Powershell GUI Array of ProgressBar
How can I change the values of the ProgressBar's after they have been created?
I dont speak english well. Sorry for the translation...
`Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$Bars                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Bars.ClientSize                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(235,125)
$Bars.text                       = "Bars"
#$Bars.icon                      = $icon
$Bars.TopMost                    = $false
$Bars.FormBorderStyle            = "FixedDialog"
$Bars.BackColor                  = "#000080"
$ProgressBarName =@('1p1', '1p2', '2p1', '2p2', '3p1', '3p2')
$i = 0
$ProgressBarName |
foreach{
    $CurrentProgressBar             = $null
    $CurrentProgressBar             = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
    $CurrentProgressBar.name        = $ProgressBarName[$i]
    $CurrentProgressBar.width       = 200
    $CurrentProgressBar.height      = 5
    $CurrentProgressBar.location    = "10,$(10+20*$i)"
    $i++
    $Bars.Controls.Add($CurrentProgressBar)
    }

#ProgessBar'1p1'.value = 50 does not work

[void]$Bars.ShowDialog()`


Try $Bars.Controls['1p1'].Value = 50
